# Covering theorem of open subsets in real, proof of uniquenesss

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The theorem states that let $V$ be any nonvoid open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a unique family $\mathbb{I}$ of open intervals such that (i) $\cup \mathbb{I}=V$, (ii) $\mathbb{I}$ is pairwise disjoint, (iii) $(a,b)\in \mathbb{I}$ implies $a$ and $b$ are not in $V$, (iv) $\mathbb{I}$ is countable.

For the proof of uniqueness, we assume as always that there are two families $\mathbb{I}, \mathbb{J}$ that fulfill the four properties described above. Now "if $J=(a,b)\in\mathbb{J}$, then $J\subset V=\cup \mathbb{I}$ (by (i)), $J \subset I$ for some $I\in\mathbb{I}$ (by (ii) and (iii) for $\mathbb{I}$)".

My question: I do not understand why do we need (iii) for $\mathbb{I}$. If $J$ is already an open interval and it is in $\cup \mathbb{I}$, then clearly $J$ cannot be in the union of two or more subsets in $\mathbb{I}$. I feel that this last condition is not necessary to ensure that $J\subset I$.

Comment: Condition (iii) is a consequence of (ii). For example, assuming that $(a,b)\in \mathbb I$ and $a\in V$, then the open interval of $\mathbb I$ that contains $a$ must have non-empty intersection with $(a,b)$.

Comment: About you statement: "If $J$ is already an open interval and it is in $\cup I$, then clearly $J$ cannot be in the union of two or more subsets in $I$." This is a direct consequence of the connectedness of $J$.

Comment: @AndréPorto Why not an official answer?

Comment: As far as I can see, this is not an answer. He is discussing on the reasons why (ii) and (iii) make sense, not actually whether or no the use of (iii) is valid in the proof.

Comment: By "valid" you mean "needed", right? Well, I was saying that (iii) is superfluous, since it is a consequence of (ii). And, if you wish, you can "avoid" passing through (iii) if you use that any open interval in $\mathbb R$ is connected. Please let me know why this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Ah, probably the reason why (iii) is needed is the fact that the author hasn't spoken of connectedness. If $(c,d)=I$, then (iii) is only needed to say that $c\leq a$ and $b\leq d$?

Comment: Precisely. And yet the author could have chosen to omit (iii) and embeded its proof. Like, assume that $a<c$, then $c\in (a,b)\subset V$. But then, fix $I'\in \mathbb I$ such that $c\in I'=(a',b')$. Then, since $I=(c,d)$ and $c\in (a',b')$, we have $a'<d$ and $c<b'$, which implies that $I\cap I' \neq\emptyset$.